# Unable to view Grid when inside hbox (layout) type container

Tags: extjs, rally

```
PieChartContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'left'
    },
    border: 1,
    style: { borderColor: '#000000', borderStyle: 'solid', borderWidth: '1px' }
});
```

then i put following grid inside:

```
var DataSummaryTable = Ext.create('Rally.ui.grid.Grid', {
    itemId: 'summaryData',
    store: Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
        data: [
            {
                Name: 'num of user stories',
                Val: NumOfStories
            },
            ....
    ....
PieChartContainer.add(DataSummaryTable);
```

If i remove the layout{...} part from container then i can see the grid. Otherwise grid is not viewable.
I am trying to put two pie charts and a small grid in an hbox layout. how do i do that?
Thanks.

Comment: After you give hbox layout have you tried using overflowY for container or either by setting its width so that scroll will be visible.It will be good if you share some fiddle.

Comment: I suspect the align property is the one causing trouble.. Either way, a fiddle would be great.

Comment: You need to specify the height of the grid

Comment: set a flex to your grid

Comment: Mr.Bruno is correct, adding a flex should resolve it. I made a fiddle to check: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1osf

Comment: Thanks Mr.Bruno and Stuart. Setting flex: 1 in Rally.ui.grid.Grid solves this issue. If i wanna make the grid to move down a little bit. How do i do that? Right now its aligned vertically to the top i wanna drag it down to center of this hbox layout. Do i need to use a place holder? Thanks.

Comment: And why does Rally.ui.grid.GridView doc doesnt show this 'flex' config? i set it to show inherited stuff as well. Its very annoying :(

Comment: Layouts are one of the most frustrating parts of ExtJS.  There is a guide in the docs to help with basics: https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/guide/layouts

Comment: In general though, everything needs to be sized from the top down.  So whatever you're adding your PieChartContainer to should have a layout or a height set.  And so on down the container hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might depend on the parent of this container. For example, if the parent of this container has a layout of 'fit', then your container should have a config flex: 1.

Comment: I am adding PieChartContainer to app level container: this.add(PieChartContainer); setting flex:1 in DataSummaryTable makes the grid visible. But i dont understand why. Can u please explain? Thanks.